# CSS Use NOT to hide items before scrolling

Tags: css, wordpress

In Wordpress, I'm trying to use the :Not Selector to hide a Menu item, until the menu becomes sticky at the top.My Nav bar, once sticky, has a class of .site-navigation-fixed that is appears in the HTML (looking at dev. console in chrome) once the bar hits the top of the screen, so I was trying to hide the first menu item until that class is active using NOT.

Is there a better way to do this, if not can someone help me with the CSS to do this. I've never used NOT and something is tripping me up in writting the CSS to make it work.

Here is my menu HTML, note the class in NAV for .site-navigation-doesn't appear until the menu is sticky at the top, otherwise before that I only have the class main-navigation.

```
<div class="navigation-top">
<div class="wrap">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation site-navigation-fixed" role="navigation" aria-label="Top Menu">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="top-menu" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
        <div class="menu-main-container">
            <ul id="top-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-57"><a title="" href="/"><img src="Home-Logo.png" style="height:80px"></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="/contact">Contact Info</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="/application">Application</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="/history">History</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
  </div><!-- .wrap -->
  </div>
```

Comment: `#site-navigation:not(.site-navigation-fixed) { display: none; }`?

Comment: unsure of what you are asking, why not hide it by default until it has the `.site-navigation-fixed` class?

Comment: @DavidNguyen sorry that was confusing,  I'm specially trying to hide <li id="menu-item-57" .... until the Nav has .site-navigation-fixed

Comment: I think I might have been making this more difficult in trying to use a single statement with a not.

Can't I just do something like this, not sure if there is a right way to do this vs what you were proposing @MichaelCoker
`#menu-item-57{display:none;}`
`.site-navigation-fixed #menu-item-57{display:inline-block;}`

Comment: @MichaelCoker I adapted your suggestion and got it working with
`.navigation-top:not(.site-navigation-fixed) #menu-item-57{ display: none; }`

thanks for showing how to properly use :not in this context.  It was really helpful.

Comment: @BillCorkill awesome np. would you like me to submit it as an answer?